# Application.Transpose stopped working when spreadsheet moved to anothe computer

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am running Office 365 on a Mac

I just got a new computer after old one died after I installed all my files from a backup one of .xlsm reports crashes with a "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" on the following line of code:
 `Results = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow).Value)`

Is there a particular reference or include file I need to run this?

Here is the complete test Sub:

```
Sub GetDataTest()

    ' IDcust_Column will hold data from column "A"
    Dim IDcust_Col() As Variant
    ' Results array will hold results
    Dim Results() As Variant
    Dim wkSh As Worksheet
    Set wkSh = shCustomers
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Initialize and fill arrays
    ' Initialize Results the correct number of blank cells from column "BZ"
    Results = Application.Transpose(wks.Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow).Value)
    
    ' Initialize IDcust_Col all data from column "A"
    IDcust_Col = Application.Transpose(wkSh.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value)
    

    For i = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
       ' Do a bunch of stuff
       
        Results(i) = IDcust_Col(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Write results to column AC
    wks.Range("AC2:AC" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(Results)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow` when this fails? (also, there was a question asked recently about `Transpose` failing on Mac, so maybe your question is related).

Comment: You have `wks` but never set it? Edit: also qualify `LastRow`.

Comment: I will bet that if you use this `LastRow = wksh.Range("A" & wksh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `Results = Application.Transpose(wksh.Range("BZ2:BZ" & LastRow).Value)` it will work.

Comment: Why are you transposing anyway?  Just treat it like a 2d array and you will not need to do the costly transpose.

Comment: ^^^^^ This is the real answer. Skip all of the transposes and use `For i = Lbound(Results, 1) to Ubound(Results, 1)`, `Results(i, 1)` = `IDcust_Col(i, 1)`.

Comment: Related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72002722/transpose-and-index-failing-after-16-60-update#comment127228578_72002722

Comment: Replies: The value of  ```LastRow``` is correctly set to the row number of the last row of data.

Comment: REPLIES: Sorry you loose your bet

Comment: You still haven't clarified the `wks` issue mentioned by @findwindow. Is it a typo and does it need to be `wksh` or something else?